# Tree in scala swing

Tags: swing, scala, jtree

I want to use a tree in my Scala swing application, but the component isn't available in the API.

Does a wrapper of `JTree` exists ?

If not, do you have any advice for making it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though you can use directly the Java JTree in your scala program, as illustrated by [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5287), there is a debate about including a Scala wrapper of a JTree.

> The following common usages are tedious, verbose, non-type safe, and/or require unsafe null usage:
>
> - Creating a custom tree model, backed by your own user objects -- the Scala
>     Swing way would be to have a standard typesafe `Map` behind it
> - Events - there are heaps of events created by trees -- `TreeWillExpandListeners`, `TreeSelection`, etc -- Using the Reactor/Publisher `PartialFunction` model would make this code far more readable and concise.
> - Editable components -- This is done with implicit values elsewhere in scala.swing, and should be here too.
> - Custom renderers -- Can't remember how Scala deals with these, but this is always fiddly in Java Swing too.
>
> Bottom line is, `JTrees` are a massive pain to use in Java, for no particularly good reason. A Scala wrapper would be a massive boon for Scala Swing users.

A [design is in progress](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-swing-JTree-wrapper-design-td2004809.html), and a [**JTree wrapper proposal is available in this GitHub repo**](http://github.com/kenbot/ScalaSwingTreeWrapper), made by [kenbot (Ken Scambler)](http://github.com/kenbot).